# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).find(...).collapse is not a function

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

In my application showing a table with inner tables and given two button to expand / collapse table. i am using attached code to expand / collapse table rows.

But its giving below error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).find(...).collapse is not a
>   function
>           at HTMLAnchorElement. (TransitPlanList.js:11)
>           at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
>           at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)

Please see below code

```js
$(document).off('click', '[id=open-button]').on('click', '[id=open-button]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse').collapse('show');
});

$(document).off('click', '[id=close-button]').on('click', '[id=close-button]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.collapse-group').find('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
    <button id="open-button" class="btn btn-info open-button btn-xs" type="button">
      Open all
    </button>
    <button id="close-button" class="btn btn-info close-button btn-xs" type="button">
      Close all
    </button>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
    <br>   <table id="tdServiceList" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SL. No.</th>
            <th>Status</th>

            <th>Service Name</th>
            <th>Public Service No</th>
            <th>Dept</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="click">[+]</a></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;1</td>
            <td>KHARWAR NAGAR-SOMESHWAR JN-NEW</td>
            <td>105</td>
            <td>BRT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <table id="tdServiceListDetails" class="table table-bordred table-striped" style="display: none;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Master Schedule Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Demo master schedule</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1036,4 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>master sch2</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1037,4 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>master schedule june</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1052,4 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="click">[+]</a></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;2</td>
            <td>UDHANA-SACHIN G.I.D.C NAKA</td>
            <td>101A</td>
            <td>BRT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <table id="tdServiceListDetails" class="table table-bordred table-striped" style="display: none;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Master Schedule Name</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1010 schedule1</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1039,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1010 sch2</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1040,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>primary master schedule</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1041,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>primary2</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1042,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>primary3</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1043,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>demo plan  new</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1044,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>surat plan</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1045,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>surat plan new</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1046,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>surat mc</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1047,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>demo surat mc</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1048,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>demo 41</td>
                            <td>
                                <button alt="View Master Schedule Plan" title="View  Master Schedule Plan" onclick="ViewMasterSchedule( 1051,1010 )" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

same code i have placed in jsfiddle.. please refer

[JSFiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/VidyaSajeev/3g2xc0vh/3/)

Comment: Your buttons expect to find a parent HTML Element with the class `collapse-group ` but there is no such element anywhere in your given code example. Also the element with class `collapse` which should be a child of `collapse-group` is no where in your code example

Comment: As far as I know, jQuery does not have any method such as collapse(). Are you using any plugin?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/VidyaSajeev/3g2xc0vh/4/> Added collapse-group div

Comment: Yes.. bootstrap.. it was missing in jsfiddle.. I have included it.
https://jsfiddle.net/VidyaSajeev/29m8od4j/1/
but still its not expanding.. but the above error got disappeared